# Implementing an ajax form with Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms

The problem I'm having is that, when I submit the form, the 
response is placed in a new url(/feedback) instead of placing it in 
the actual(/results) url. The alert never gets executed. 
I guess I'm doing something wrong in the template but I can't find the solution.

I debugged the view and made a `request.is_ajax()`, it returned False.

views.py:

```
def ajax_feedback(request): 
    success = False 
    if request.method == "POST": 
        post = request.POST.copy() 
        if post.has_key('rel') and post.has_key('relp'): 
                rel = post['rel'] 
                relp = post['relp'] 
                q = post['query'] 
                fq = post['full_query'] 
                fq = fq[:350] 
                ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] 
                feedback = FeedBack(q=q, ip_address=ip,
                                   user=request.user, relevance=rel, rel_pages=relp, 
                                   full_query=fq) 
                feedback.save() 
                success = True 
    if success == True: 
        return HttpResponse("Success") 
    else: 
        return HttpResponse("Error")
```

results.html:

```
<form method="post" action="/feedback/" id="feedback_form"> 
    <input type="radio" name="rel" value="yes" id="rel" /> Yes<br /> 
    <input type="radio" name="rel" value="no" id="rel" /> No 
    <input type="radio" name="relp" value="1-5" id="relp" /> 1-5 <br /> 
    <input type="radio" name="relp" value="6-10" id="relp" /> 6-10 
    <input type="hidden" name="query" value="{{ query }}"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="full_query" value="{{ bq }}"> 
    <input id="create" type="submit" value="Send"> 
</form> 
<script> 
      var create_note = function() { 
      var rel = $("#rel").val() 
      var relp = $("#relp").val() 
      var query = {{ query }} 
      var full_query = {{ bq }} 
      var data = { rel:rel, relp:relp, query:query, full_query:full_query }; 
      var args = { 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "/feedback/", 
            data: data, 
            success: function(msg){ 
                 alert(msg); 
            }
      } 
      $.ajax(args); 
      return false; 
    }; 
    $("#create").click(create_note); 
</script>
```

urls.py:

```
... 
(r'^feedback/$', views.ajax_feedback), 
(r'^results/(?P<query>.+)/$', views.results), 
...
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you say the problem is that it is going to /feedback/ except that is what you're posting to in your jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I want it to go to feedback but without showing the response in another page.

Answer (score -1):

You have a missing close brace after your `success` function declaration. Because of this, the `return false` is never reached, and your browser submits the form via normal HTTP request - which is why it's not an Ajax call when it reaches your view.

**Edit** well another JS bug is that you haven't put `{{ query }}` and `{{ bp }}` in quotes. They might or might not be valid JS objects, and if not the function will fail and never reach the `return false`.

Comment: The close brace missing here is in the code. Sorry, I edited the post, I must've deleted it by mistake.